# Bigquery to Avro

Tags: google-bigquery, avro, python-bigquery

I currently run a SQL Query to extract data from a Public BigQuery dataset into a Table, from there I can easily use the Export function to generate a Avro file and save it into GCS. How to generate this file programmatically?
I have used BQ API to read a table into a Pandas Dataframe, is the best option to read to Pandas DF and then export it to Avro? Or is the a better way to do it.

Comment: Why don't you export to Avro directly? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#avro_export_details

Comment: @ECris, will you be able to post your suggestion as an answer to this thread for the benefit of the community?

Comment: @PhilippSh, added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you [export to Avro](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#avro_export_details) directly? 
This will do a table export to Avro in GCS bucket.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery 

client = bigquery.Client()
project = project
dataset_id = 'cdc'
table_id = 'project_tycho_reports'
bucket_name ='bucketname'

destination_uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, 'fileName')
dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id, project=project)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
job_config.destination_format = bigquery.DestinationFormat.AVRO

extract_job = client.extract_table(
        table_ref,
        destination_uri,
        job_config=job_config,
        location="EU",
        )  
extract_job.result()
```

I saw that there is also the possibility to specify [compression](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/JobConfiguration#JobConfigurationExtract) (not available when exporting from UI) something like  `job_config.compression = bigquery.Compression.SNAPPY`
Hope it helps.